# Is there a way i can show a vertical line in the center of MpAndroidChart Horizontal Bar?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to show a zero line in the center of my horizontal bar chart,  however, the line is showing at the end.

here is my code

```
        val left = chart.axisLeft
        left.setDrawLabels(false) // no axis labels
        left.setDrawAxisLine(false) // no axis line
        left.setDrawGridLines(false) // no grid lines
        left.setDrawZeroLine(true) // draw a zero line
        chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false // no right axis
```

[image: Chart]

Comment: do same as left axis for right axis

Comment: still not working